# "Trying to get property of non-object" in SOAP PHP - not sure why this error is occuring

Tags: php, soap

Hope you guys can help me... Still new at PHP and I am struggling to display parts of this Object/Array set of Results.
I am getting the following result `$results` back from a SOAP webservice:

```
`object(stdClass)[9]
      public 'Summary' => 
          object(stdClass)[2]
                 public 'ID' => string '1096408402' (length=10)
                 public 'IKey' => string '1440010962' (length=10)
      public 'Address' => 
          object(stdClass)[4]
  public 'Forename' => string 'TEST' (length=4)
  public 'Surname' => string 'TESTER' (length=6)
  public 'DOB' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
  public 'Telephone' => string 'Unavailable' (length=11)
  public 'Occupants' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[12]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[13]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[14]
          ...
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[15]
          ...
```

Now I am attempting to put the data into a table format.

I have been successful in creating the table using a `foreach` on the section marked `Occupants`. I do this by calling `Occupants` as follows:
    `$occupants = ($results->Address->Occupants);` and the data is extracted and populated into my table using my code (not relevent for this question).

My problem now is that when I try and do the same for `Summary` or `Address` it doesnt work: I get the error "**Trying to get property of non-object**"

I have tried `$summary = $results->Summary` and `$summary = $results['Summary']` and neither works.

What I then want to do is run 
`<?php $summary = ($results->Summary);foreach($summary as $person):?>`
and then I insert it into my table as follows:
`<td><?=$person->ID?></td>`

So any idea why I get this error? I dont think it is in the `foreach` aspect...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should get the "Summary" object with:

```
$summary = $results->Summary
```

in this case `$summary` is an object with 2 properties: "ID" and "IKey".
If you iterate over `$summary` with `foreach`, the value of `$person` would have the value of `$summary->ID` in the first loop iteration and the value of `$summary->IKey` in the second loop iteration. Both `$summary->ID` and `$summary->IKey` are strings and therefore non-objects, so I think that is why you get the error.
I suppose that you want do do this:

```
$summary = $results->Summary;
foreach ($summary as $value)
  echo "<td>$value</td>";
```

This should output (for the given example):

```
<td>1096408402</td><td>1440010962</td>
```

For more information about Object Iteration, I recommend: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php